# UnicodeDecodeError(utf-8) occurs when I load the model in [Object Detection_setting for drawing result with checkpoints] process

Tags: python, utf-8, anaconda

how's it going!!

This is my first question, so I may be lacking a lot. It's my first time working on machine learning, but I don't want to give up here. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

I currently set up an environment to use the object detection model at the Anaconda prompt. And now I work to view the results on the Jupyter notebook.

DecodeError often occurred in the environment setting stage, but as I created the virtual environment several times, I was able to move on somehow

**Could you read this PLEASE?**

first, after running the code on Jupyter notebook like this,,

```
import os, fnmatch
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'    # Suppress TensorFlow logging (1)

import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf
#tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')           # Suppress TensorFlow logging (2)

listOffiles = os.listdir('./test_data-1')  ##### 수정
Img_filenames = []
print(listOffiles)
# Enable GPU dynamic memory allocation
#gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
#for gpu in gpus:
#    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

def Load_images():
    base_path = "C:\tf_1125\workspace\training_demo\test_data-1/"   #####수정
    pattern = "*.jpg"  #####수정
    for entry in listOffiles: ## Get file names
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
            entry = base_path + entry
            Img_filenames.append(str(entry))
            #print(entry)
    image_paths = []

    for filename in Img_filenames:
        #image_path = base_path + filename
        image_path = filename
        #image_path = pathlib.Path(image_path)
        image_paths.append(str(image_path))
        #print(filename)
    return image_paths

IMAGE_PATHS = Load_images()
print (IMAGE_PATHS)
```

Next, I load the models.

```
import time
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from object_detection.builders import model_builder

PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR = "C:\tf_1125\workspace\training_demo\models\my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn"  #####수정

PATH_TO_CFG = PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR + "/pipeline.config"
PATH_TO_CKPT = PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR + "/"

print('Loading model... ', end='')
start_time = time.time()

# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(PATH_TO_CFG)
model_config = configs['model']
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=model_config, is_training=False)

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'ckpt-1')).expect_partial()

@tf.function
def detect_fn(image):
    """Detect objects in image."""

    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)

    return detections

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print('Done! Took {} seconds'.format(elapsed_time))
```

**The problem is here!** In this process, I met ‘UnicodeDecodeError ’

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13256/3247142710.py in <module>
     14 
     15 # Load pipeline config and build a detection model
---> 16 configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(PATH_TO_CFG)
     17 model_config = configs['model']
     18 detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=model_config, is_training=False)

c:\anaconda\envs\tenf\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\config_util.py in get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config_path, config_override)
    136   pipeline_config = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()
    137   with tf.gfile.GFile(pipeline_config_path, "r") as f:
--> 138     proto_str = f.read()
    139     text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)
    140   if config_override:

c:\anaconda\envs\tenf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py in read(self, n)
    115       string if in string (regular) mode.
    116     """
--> 117     self._preread_check()
    118     if n == -1:
    119       length = self.size() - self.tell()

c:\anaconda\envs\tenf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py in _preread_check(self)
     78                                            "File isn't open for reading")
     79       self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
---> 80           compat.path_to_str(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
     81 
     82   def _prewrite_check(self):
```

UTF-8 => Even though I decode UTF-8(through decoding exe file or notepad++), there is no sign of resolution. If there's anyone who solved the same error as me, please share your knowledge!

Thank you for reading my comment. :)

Comment: On Windows, files are generally not UTF-8 encoded. Why do you think that `pipeline.config` should be utf8? What is the encoding used in notepad++?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Serge-ballesta. I didn't think pipeline.config should be utf9. but in my process, utf8 error occurs repeatably. and now I can't enter my env (by utf8 error). So I will install anaconda from  the beginning and retry this!!

Comment: Hi furas. You mean when I upload my question, the error message should placed first paragraph? I want everyone understand my situation easily, so I wrote this in order. Thanks your advice!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably below solution will work:

open `c:\anaconda\envs\tenf\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\config_util.py` file and **change line no 137** as:

```
with tf.gfile.GFile(pipeline_config_path, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
```

Changes should be reverted back for other projects if config is not written with Unicode encoding.

Comment: Oh Thank you for your answer! I will try this definitely. but now I faced 'env enter error'. so I reinstall anaconda and retry this!